# fullcalendar - display time in dayGridWeek

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use fullcalendar to display events but I have problem. How to display time in left in dayGridWeek?

code js :

```
var displayDisponibiltyBabySitter = function(){
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('disponiblity');
            if(calendarEl){
                var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    defaultView: 'dayGridWeek' ,
                    validRange: function(nowDate){
                        return {start: nowDate}
                    },
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                    },
                    locale: _mpop.current_lang,
                    timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
                    eventBackgroundColor : "#444",
                    eventTextColor: '#EEE',
                    slotDuration: '00:60:00',
                    slotLabelFormat: [
                        {
                            hour: '2-digit',
                            minute: '2-digit',
                            hour12: false
                        }
                    ],
                    views: {
                        dayGridWeek: {
                            eventTimeFormat: {
                                hour: 'numeric',
                                minute: '2-digit',
                                omitZeroMinute: true,
                                meridiem: 'narrow'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    events: Routing.generate('front.babysitter.disponibilities',{'id': $("#dispo-babysitter").data("id")}),
                    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ]
                });
                calendar.render();
            }

        };
```

thanks in advance

I have this result:
[image]

but how to get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got your defaultView set as 'dayGridWeek'

set it to:

```
defaultView: 'timeGridWeek'
```

and you should be fine...

Comment: @dev109 this should work. What exactly is going wrong? Do you get an error in the Console? Are all your plugins loaded correctly?

Comment: @ADyson no error in console but list hours not display in dayGridWeek :(

Comment: I use full calendar v4 and now after search i found this example for full calendar v2 : http://jsfiddle.net/e78b944d/1/ it work here in version 2 but in version 4 dosen't work :(

Comment: @dev109 "hours not display in dayGridWeek" ...yes that's the correct behaviour for **day**Grid. For hours to show up you have to use **time**Grid as this answer is telling you. Here's a demo, using your code, but swapping dayGrid for timeGrid. It works fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BeOGdV . P.S. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view for the difference between these two types of view. P.S What was correct code in v2 or v3 is irrelevant, it is completely different to v4, v4 was a total re-write of almost everything.